# You must feed a value for placeholder tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, tensorboard, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement an lstm nn using tesorboarb and I am receiving this error message: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'performance_1/loss_summary'.

I have already searched for an answer in many question without result.

```
with tf.name_scope('performance'):
loss = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=None,name='loss_summary') 
    tf_loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
    tf_accuracy_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=None, name='accuracy_summary') 
    tf_accuracy_summary = tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', tf_accuracy_ph)

# Gradient norm summary
for g in gradients:
for var in v:
    if 'hidden3' in var.name and 'w' in var.name:
        with tf.name_scope('Gradients'):
            tf_last_grad_norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(g**2))
            tf_gradnorm_summary = tf.summary.scalar('grad_norm', tf_last_grad_norm)
            break   

# Merge all summaries together
performance_summaries = tf.summary.merge([tf_loss_summary,tf_accuracy_summary])
```

The other part of the code in which I get the error is:

```
for ep in range(epochs):       

for step in range(train_seq_length//batch_size):

    u_data, u_labels = data_gen.unroll_batches()

    feed_dict = {}
    for ui,(dat,lbl) in enumerate(zip(u_data,u_labels)):            
        feed_dict[train_inputs[ui]] = dat.reshape(-1,1)
        feed_dict[train_outputs[ui]] = lbl.reshape(-1,1)

    feed_dict.update({tf_learning_rate: 0.0001, tf_min_learning_rate:0.000001})

    _, l = session.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)

    average_loss += l


if (ep+1) % valid_summary == 0:

    average_loss = average_loss/(valid_summary*(train_seq_length//batch_size))

  # The average loss
    if (ep+1)%valid_summary==0:
        print('Average loss at step %d: %f' % (ep+1, average_loss))

    train_mse_ot.append(average_loss)

    average_loss = 0 # reset loss

    predictions_seq = []

    mse_test_loss_seq = []
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initiliaze `loss` as a variable. When you define something as a placeholder, you have to feed it's value when running the graph dependent on it.

Comment: I have initialized `loss` as a variable and it worked. Also I have changed `average_loss += l` to `average_loss += sum(l)`.
Does it mean that if I would like to use summaries, I most not use a placeholder ?
Thank you for your help !

Comment: Probably. You need to understand variables, placeholders and constants. If my answer is helpful upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

`loss` is a placeholder, so you have to give a value to it. You probably didn't notice it and overrode your actual loss function. Usually summaries are not placeholders, so you have a misunderstanding of your variables and the flow in you code.